# What is the plural of "copy" when applied to the output of copywriters?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, collective-nouns

If a [Copywriter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copywriting) produces several articles for printing, what are his works collectively known as?

I feel the answer is not *copies* as this would indicate it is several articles reproduced from an original.

I wonder if it might be *copy*, a bit like how *data* is plural?

Comment: "... a bit like how data is plural", not so. *Copy* is not plural here. It is the term for the body of writing as a whole -- which may consist of one or more pieces.

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is correct.  When used to mean 'material for printing', *copy* refers to any number of works (even if it's just a single one).  Note that you would also not refer to it as *a copy* as in:

> I wrote a copy for the magazine.

Comment: +1: Exactly. "Copy" is a word like water. You can measure the amount of copy you write just as you can measure the amount of water you drink. You can drink, say, two glasses of water or a whole gallon just as you can write 15 or 3,000 words of copy. But however much you write, it's all just copy.

Comment: @Robusto - I like the comparison to fluids.  I'll be sure to steal that for similar examples in the future =D

Comment: +1, good answer!  One suggestion: when quoting an *incorrect* usage like you do here, it’s customary to prefix it with a star, eg **This sentence ungrammatical.* so that it’s less likely to be mistaken as an example of correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

"I wrote many sales letters today". Why would it be "I wrote many sales copy today"? They mean the same thing.

I have many copies of her book.

Comment: the 'copy' of a copywriter and 'copies of' a written work - are different concepts.